# Getting same output out of function* (generator)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, and i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Working example:

```js
function* range(start) {
 let value = +start;
 while (true) {
  const str = "" + value;
  yield "0".repeat(start.length - str.length) + str;
  value++;
 }
}

function GenerateNumber(str) {
 var iterator = range(str);
 var interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(iterator.next().value);
 }, 1100);
}

GenerateNumber("0137");
```

Non working example:

```js
function* range(start) {
 let value = +start;
 while (true) {
  const str = "" + value;
  yield "0".repeat(start.length - str.length) + str;
  value++;
 }
}

function repeat(str) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(str);
  GenerateNumber(str);
 }, 1500);
}

function GenerateNumber(str) {
 var iterator = range(str);
 repeat(iterator.next().value);
}
GenerateNumber("0137");
```

As you can see in first example numbers increase like they should, but when im trying to increase number on every function call, it displays the same value. Even tho i set .next().value as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a new iterator every time `GenerateNumber()` is called, which starts from the beginning:

```
function GenerateNumber(str) {
    var iterator = range(str);  // <-- creates a brand new iterator
    repeat(iterator.next().value);
}
```

You need to keep calling `next()` on the same iterator. For example if you checked whether `iterator` was already assigned:

```js
function* range(start) {
 let value = +start;
 while (true) {
  const str = "" + value;
  yield "0".repeat(start.length - str.length) + str;
  value++;
 }
}

function repeat(str) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(str);
  GenerateNumber(str);
 }, 1500);
}

var iterator
function GenerateNumber(str) {
 iterator = iterator || range(str); // << -- do we alreay have an iterator?
 repeat(iterator.next().value);
}
GenerateNumber("0137");
```

Comment: I am so dumb... lifesaver :) Thanks!